# Как найти файл на сайте bitrix, который выводит опредененный блок информации в хедере?

Tags: файлы, битрикс, консоль, cms, шаблоны

Волею судеб разбираюсь с интернет-сайтом на битрикс.
В хедере есть такой элемент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
где заказать звонок написано и телефон указан:
Если на сайте переходишь в режим редактирования, то у соседних элементов доступно меню "Изменить область", но у этого элемента при наведении - ничего. Значит он как-то по особому выводится...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как (может быть, с помощью консоли) найти, что выводит эту информацию, чтобы сделать там изменения. Перерыл весь шаблон, в консоли копался тоже. Например, по адресу структура сайта - файлы и папки - bitrix - templates нет header.php, который вроде бы должен выводить это, есть только footer

Comment: В некоторых решениях для магазина, например, в корне лежат файлы такие `sect_address.php, sect_phone.php`

Comment: в моем случае webcomp.market стоит...

Comment: Нужные **headers** могут быть еще здесь `local\templates\webcomp.market\headers` или `bitrix\templates\webcomp.market\headers`